# Query object by id using react-query v4

Tags: jquery, reactjs, react-query

I have react component where I call react query

```
  const blogQuery = useQuery(['blog'], getBlog(id));
```

Then I have api.js file where I store api calls

```
export const getBlog = async (id) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/blogs/${id}`);
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    throw new Error('An error occurred while fetching Blogs');
  }
};
```

In my HTML part of react component I have error checker that triggers error if something happend wrong.

```
blogQuery.error.message
            ? 'error.message = ' + blogQuery.error.message
            : 'error = ' + blogQuery.error
```

As a result I receive the following error on the screen

> error = Missing queryFn

Why is that happening ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to add getBlog as function, now its just called
and id as key to refetch when key is changed
change this :

```
  const blogQuery = useQuery(['blog'], getBlog(id));
```

to  this :

```
  const blogQuery = useQuery(['blog',id], ()=> getBlog(id));
```

Comment: would be good if you could amend your answer please. copy-pasting this exact code will lead to bugs along the way...